# Deleting a specific value from a database with Jersey

Tags: rest, http, parameters, jersey

I have a couchdb that contains a number of files and I want to delete a specific file, based on a unique id. This doesn't work with any kind of parameters, PathParams/QueryParams. The code reads the parameters, takes in the value and then either ignores three request or treats it differently than a normal DELETE I can't really tell at this point.

Is there any other way to specify  this data to the DELETE function?

Comment: Are you saying  you are able to get the params in the REST API. In that case its your responsibility to then take that value and continue with your logic ie delete of files. What do you mean by treats it differently?

Comment: @Integrator I honestly don't know how to explain it much further then that. The logic checks out and the parameter goes in it just doesn't do what its supposed to be doing. I've read in a few places that some frameworks treat DELETEs with a request value as a POST rather then a delete so that might be happening. I'm not asking why that's happening or how to fix that anymore, I am looking for an alternative to using parameters to pass the value.

Comment: If you paste some code that you think is not working might help SO users to comment on it.

Comment: I can assure you the code is functional, Ive debugged it and the values goes through as expected, all the calls are reached as expected. At this point I thought the backend might have been broken so Itested by adding the identifier directly into the method. This however only worked after I removed the @PathParam from the begining of the method.

Which leads me to the question Im asking, is there any way to send that value without path, query, or field params?

Comment: Any way, i see you asked another question. I pasted this as answer on the other one. You can send information to a RESTful service as either headers, path param, query param or message body.If all the values go through as expected there is no problem with jax-rs/jersey. Now you need to debug the code and fix your implementation. jax-rs will only match a DELETE call with the DELETE http method you have implemented.
It is then your responsibility to actually perform a DELETE operation of the resource within the method. jax-rs or jersey is not going to complain if you do not DELETE.